# What happens to current HTTP request when we deploy Firebase Function?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

Let's say there is an HTTP request currently being processed then we deploy the same function simultaneously.

What will happen to the current HTTP request? Will it be cancelled? or Firebase will wait before proceeding to deploy?

Answer (score 2):

> Instances provisioned with your function's previous version may
> continue running (and processing traffic) for several minutes after a
> deployment has finished. **This ensures that traffic sent to your
> function while a deployment is in progress will not be dropped**.

From the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/deploying#migrating_between_deployments)

---

So, in other words, the current HTTP request will be executed. It's only when the deployment is completed and the platform needs to spin up a new Cloud Function instance that your new version will be used. Note that several instances of your Cloud Function can run in parallel if necessary: In one instance, events are treated one after the other, in serial.

Comment: *firebaser here* This is indeed correct: any existing requests will be handled by your previous code. But your new code is deployed immediately even when other requests are still active, and new requests that arrive after that deploy will be handled by the new code. So you may momentarily have two versions of your code running, each on different container(s).